# How to add copyright theme designer company

Tags: magento-1.9, footer

How to add copyright with logo in footer with logo ?

> ( copyright for company which has designed the website )

Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

1.Go to admin **Cms->static block->add a new block** then add the logo and copyright as you want something like this:

```
<div class="logo-copyright">
    <div class="logo">
        <img src="{{skin url="images/logo-name-here.png"}}"> //you upload the image in : skin/frontend/{your package}/{your theme}/images/logo-name-here.png
    </div>
    <div class="copyright">
        <p>copyright here</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

2. Go to **app/design/frontend/{your package}/{your theme}/template/page/html/footer.phtml** then add the code bellow where your want to display your copyright that your enter in the step1

```
<div class="custom-block">
    <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('block_identifiant')->toHtml(); ?>
</div>
```

3. Clear the cache.

Answer (score 0):

If the theme you're using follows magento core theme standards, then you should be able to add your html markup in the admin, without having to edit any templates (*.phtml files).

Go to `System > Configuration > General | Design > Footer > Copyright`.

If that doesn't work then you need either include the copyright field in your template (look at magento core `/template/page/html/footer.phtml`) or add a new static block (read the other answer on how to do this).

[image: System >Config >Design >Footer]

Answer (score 0):

You are required to edit `footer.phtml` in you theme

```
app/design/frontend/{your package}/{your theme}/template/page/html/footer.phtml
```